# How can I measure area of contour using another contour's size as reference?

Tags: python, opencv

[image]

Hello.
I have bunch of images like example i uploaded.

There are always rotated ellipse and smaller rectangle-like contour.

I will always set the smaller rectangle's width as 1.

That is, the smaller rectangle's width will be the reference size for measuring ellipse's size.

I am using python, and considering using opencv.

How can I measure the ellipse's area, while considering smaller rectangle's width 1?

If my question is ambiguous, feel free to make some replies.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way using Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Convert to gray
- Threshold
- Floodfill the outer white border with black
- Get the contours
- Get the area of the largest contour (ellipse)
- Get the bounding box of the smallest contour (rectangle)
- Draw contours on input (red for ellipse and blue for rectangle)
- Compute the ratio of the ellipse area divided by the rectangle width
- Save Results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('ellipse_rect.jpg')

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,128,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
h, w = thresh.shape

# create zeros mask 2 pixels larger in each dimension
mask = np.zeros([h + 2, w + 2], np.uint8)

# floodfill outer white border with black
thresh_filled = cv2.floodFill(thresh, mask, (0,0), (0), (0), (0), flags=8)[1]

# get contour
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh_filled, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]

# get area of largest contour -- assume it is ellipse
ellipse_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
ellipse_contour_area = cv2.contourArea(ellipse_contour)

# draw ellipse contour on input in red
result = img.copy()
cv2.drawContours(result, [ellipse_contour], 0, (0,0,255), 1)

# get bounding box of small contour
rectangle_contour = min(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(rectangle_contour)

# draw rectangle contour on input in blue
cv2.drawContours(result, [rectangle_contour], 0, (255,0,0), 1)

# get ellipse area in units of rectangle width
ellipse_area_calibrated = ellipse_contour_area / w
print("ellipse area:", ellipse_area_calibrated)


# save cropped image
cv2.imwrite('ellipse_rect_thresh.png',thresh)
cv2.imwrite('ellipse_rect_thresh_filled.png',thresh_filled)
cv2.imwrite('ellipse_rect_contours.png',result)

# show the images
cv2.imshow("THRESH", thresh)
cv2.imshow("FILLEd", thresh_filled)
cv2.imshow("contours", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Threshold Image:

[image]

Flood Filled Threshold Image:

[image]

Contours Image:

[image]

Comment: Love your answer. Just one question) because area's unit is square, in calibrating ellipse's contour area, i think dividing by w^2 may be better. Is it right?